# ¿Cómo obtengo los valores de los intervalos realizados en R?

Tags: r

Hice la categorización con cut para temperatura y no tuve problema, pero ahora para la variable visibilidad tengo la dificultad de poder generar los siguientes intervalos: [0, 200>, [0, 400>, [0, 600>, [0, 800>, [0, 1000>, [0,1500>, [0,3000>, [0, 5000>, [0, 8000>, así como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código que utilicé para categorizar temperatura:

```
cut(TE, breaks=c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25,30,35,40),
                             right = F, include.lowest = T))
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

`cut()` genera finalmente un `factor`, las etiquetas de cada categoría se construyen automáticamente a menos que definas el parámetro `labels`:

```
cut(TE, 
    breaks = c(200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1500, 3000, 8000),
    labels = c('<200', '<400', '<600', '<800', '<1000', '<1500', '<3000', '<8000'),
    right = FALSE, 
    include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Una consulta, y cómo podría generar intervalos que sean por ejemplo: [0, 200>, [0, 400>, [0, 600>, [0, 800> y así sucesivamente?.

Comment: Yo interpreté que tu pregunta iba por el lado de las "etiquetas" no de los intervalos. Para definir estos usas el parámetro `breaks`, por ej: `breaks = c(0, 200, 400, ...)`

Comment: Sí, pero cuando uso breaks, me generan los intervalos: [0,200>, [200, 400>, y así sucesivamente, pero no sabia como podía generar los intervalos de [0, 200>, [0, 400> y así . . .

Comment: Una cosas son los rangos, que se configuran mediante `breaks` y otra  el texto que quieres para cada rango que se configura por `labels`. Saludos